# How to break a large map into smaller parts (tiles), for printing, in QGIS

Tags: qgis, mapping

We have a map a very wide area. We want to break it into, for example 8, mutually exclusive parts, so we can print each one separately and, if needed, put them all together and remake the whole map.

There seems to be no way in Map Composer to automatically break the map into parts, and doing things manually would not be precise.

Is there any way to automate this?

Comment: Have you tried using the Atlas generation?

Comment: Do you mean breaking it into individual maps with their own scale, legend, etc - or printing sections of one larger map?

Comment: @Simbamangu Yes, with their own scale and legend

Comment: @MorganEllingham I did, but was not successful. Is that the way to do it?

Comment: That would be the way I would do it. You would need to have your 8 "parts" as an actual boundary layer in your map and use that as your "coverage" layer.

Comment: @Pep, if it wasn't successful, could you edit your question to explain what you tried, and what didn't work?